# how to change ShortDate Format in Win XP VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datetime, windows-xp

i have problem with Shortdate format i have tried below code its working in Win 7 but not working in Win XP

Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International", "sShortDate","dd/MM/yyyy")

PLease Help

Comment: Are you *trying* to change it system-wide, or do you just want different results in your app?

Comment: i want change it System-Wide

Comment: In that case I suggest you try to look for APIs to do it, which don't depend on the OS-version-specific registry locations.

Comment: but the above code is working in WIN 7

Comment: Yes, presumably because the way the i18n settings are stored in the registry is different in Windows 7. That's why I suggested that you try to find an API which will have been implemented appropriately in each version.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374049(v=vs.85).aspx for example - although note the warnings about it. (This isn't the kind of thing I'd expect many apps to do...)